# SQL Selecting multiple rows based on binary to decimal conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry the title is a little vague.

I have inherited a table like this...

```
HG_ID | HG_Description
1     | Blue
2     | Red
4     | Green
8     | Yellow
16    | White
32    | Violet
64    | Black
```

The information is based on a 7 bit binary eg 
0000001 represents Blue
0000011 Represents Blue + Red

I have another table that contains the decimal equivalent.

```
0000001 = 1 in the second table
0000011 = 3 in the second table.
```

My issue is that if I have 66 in the second table I don't know how to do a select statement that gives me Black and Red in the same cell.

I know how to do it on the numbers that appear the same in each table but not when there is more than one selection.

I hope I have made that clear it is my first post.

Thank you.
Mal

Comment: Sorry they were meant to be two columns so 1 in the first column is blue in the second. 2 in the first column is Red in the second.

Comment: This is not clear. What is the exact relationship between numbers and colours?

Comment: The number tells me what colour to pick based on the decimal from the second table so 3 represents Blue & red. Not sure if you mean something else

Comment: If that table would have been defined with 7 columns of type Bit, SQL Server would take care of all the management headaches for you. You would have also saved some space. Of course it is probably too late to change it.

Comment: Yeah the problem is you inherit these things and just have to live with them.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the appropriate rows from this table using the bitwise-and operator `&`. For example ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd828/2)):

```
DECLARE @colorValue int = 66

SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE HG_ID & @colorValue = HG_ID
```

You can then use the `FOR XML PATH('')` trick to simulate MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT()` function and get this down to one row ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd828/5)):

```
DECLARE @colorValue int = 66

SELECT STUFF(
    (SELECT ', ' + CAST(HG_Description AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
     FROM Table1 
     WHERE HG_ID & @colorValue = HG_ID
     FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '')
```

---

You can of course use this to select from another table. Assume you have a table `Table2` with the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Table2
    ([COLOR] int);

INSERT INTO Table2
    ([COLOR])
VALUES
    (66),
    (23),
    (49)
;
```

The query, extended from above,

```
SELECT Table2.COLOR AS id,
    STUFF(
    (SELECT ', ' + CAST(HG_Description AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
     FROM Table1 
     WHERE HG_ID & Table2.COLOR = HG_ID
     FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '') AS Colors
FROM Table2
```

Will produce the following results ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9fa18/2)):

```
ID  COLORS
66  Red, Black
23  Blue, Red, Green, White
49  Blue, White, Violet
```

Comment: Thank you I couldn't ask for a more complete answer than that.